# Xcode UI Test: How to check what is the next XCUIElement before proceed test

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I am on page 1 and want to navigate to page 2. However when I make 
a http Get request on page 1, it will return error if the server is busy, and I will display the error with alert view, however if the request was successful, then I will navigate to page 2. Besides that, if my http Get request is return error, I will repeat to call the http Get request until able to proceed to page 2. The problem now is how do I know what will be the next UI that will appear, currently I using below code to check the next element that will appear but this method will terminate the test when the element is not found. Any solution that can check if element A found then proceed step A, else if element B then step B. Sorry for my English and long sentence.

[image]

```
XCUIElement *label = self.app.staticTexts[@"Page 2"];   
NSPredicate *exists = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"exists == 1"];  

[self expectationForPredicate:exists evaluatedWithObject:label handler:nil];   
[self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:10.0f handler:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your tests are not deterministic: You are unable to determine whether the response from the server will be successful or not. To remove this non-determinism introduced by the server, you can stub or mock the request to the server.

You can either create a mock server which is set up to send a particular response under certain conditions, or you can use a stubbing framework to stub the response within the app.

I use [OHHTTPStubs](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHHTTPStubs) to do this. Just Eat have written a [good blog post](http://tech.just-eat.com/2015/11/23/offline-ui-testing-on-ios-with-stubs/) about how to implement it for UI tests, although you will need to translate it from Objective-C if you are using Swift.

Comment: Thank you for your time, however this is not a good choice for me since I must testing my app on real live (production) server as requirement. So there is no other way?

Comment: If you're not able to control the response of the server, you won't be able to tell what you're going to test. You could have a big if/else statement depending on what UI elements are found during the test, but it is very bad practice not to know what each test is testing and you wouldn't know whether you'd tested both scenarios.